# XSD Namespace to C# Namespace

Tags: c#, namespaces

We are looking for a way to have C# autogenerate classes from an XSD and create C# namespaces using the namespace info in the XSD.

Doesnt seem like you can create a structured (xxxx.yyyy.zzzz) C# namespace from the XSD?

Is there a trick we're missing?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add some details? What have you tried? What didn't work?

Comment: Can't you just strip the 'http' and slashes from the namespace URL and create a c# namespace by replacing slashes with dots? (e.g. http://mydomain.com/myservice/1.0 = namespace mydomain.com.myservice.1.0

Answer (score 41):

Would this do the trick? the /n allows you to specify a namespace to put the generated class in.

```
xsd.exe /classes MyXSDInput.xsd /n:MyCsharpNamespace
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a really interesting project [XSD2Code](http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/) on Codeplex. It basically does the same as `xsd.exe` - only better, on the command line, and as a Visual Studio plugin.

You just right-click on an XSD file in your solution explorer and run the tool!

[alt text http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=Xsd2Code&DownloadId=41336](http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=Xsd2Code&DownloadId=41336)

You can set any valid .NET namespace as the target namespace for your generated code files.

**Update:** the XSD2Code tool has been further developed and is now offered as both a free and a paid, commercial tool - [see the official home page for more details](http://www.xsd2code.com/).

Comment: This tools (Xsd2Code) might be extremely useful but I cannot use it in nVS2012. I tried both the add-on from VS Gallery, and the download from Codeplex. None worked, so I vote - 1 down for your answer.

Comment: @achristov: sorry to hear - but I cannot reproduce your issues - I just downloaded the tool again, from Codeplex, installed it, restarted Visual Studio, and I can use the XSD2Code tool just fine. A downvote seems a bit harsh - if there's a problem, then it would be the **author's** job to fix it, and I shouldn't be *punished* for such a problem ....

Comment: This tool does things the XSD.exe tool does not do by default. If you're no XML master and not familiar with namespaces and all that, try this tool. It's not freeware, but the first 15 days are free.