# How do XML Schema namespaces map to C# class namespaces?

Tags: c#, .net

For an XSD document such as this, say I was to create a C# class using some tool like xsd.exe or xsd2code, How do I define the namespace each class belongs to?  Or do they all belong to only one namespace?

```
    ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsd:schema     targetNamespace="http://com.ibm.wbit.comptest.controller" 
        xmlns:Q1="http://com.ibm.wbit.comptest.controller" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:complexType name="TestResults">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="testSuites" type="Q1:TestSuiteRun"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="testProject" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="TestSuiteRun">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="Q1:TestRun">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="testCases" type="Q1:TestCaseRun">
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>

                <xsd:attribute name="tests" type="xsd:int"/>

            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="TestCaseRun">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="Q1:TestRun">
                <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="result" type="Q1:Severity"/>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="variations" type="Q1:VariationRun">
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:attribute name="variationCount" type="xsd:int"/>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="VariationRun">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="Q1:TestRun">
                <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="result" type="Q1:Severity"/>
      <xsd:element name="exception" nillable="true" type="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:documentation>
                                This element is used to display the exception of a failure or error.
                            </xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>             
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="Severity">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="pass"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="fail"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="error"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:complexType name="TestRun">
        <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="startTime" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="endTime" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="result" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: [XSD Namespace to C# Namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843209/xsd-namespace-to-c-sharp-namespace) ?

Comment: @JeffMercado mmm, not sure if that helps, I know how to specify the namespace using xsd2code.   I have multiple XSD documents that work together, and I don't know for each document I convert to c# class, if I need to use the same namespace or specify a new one.  I want to match as best I can the structure of all the XSD documents I'm using